# R code for repeatedly updated data matrix X and response y

Tags: r

I have a data matrix X and response variable y. After performing a function on X and y and get updated the data matrix say X1 and response y1. Now, I perform the same function on X1 and y1 and get updated the data matrix as X2 and response y2. I am interested to repeat this process for a certain number of times. How can, I reduce this labor. any one with an R code, please ???
the scratch code is provided here.

```
#rm(list=ls())
library(MASS)
p<-4
set.seed(88)
mu<-rep(0,p)
sigma<-diag(p)
n<-1000
x<-mvrnorm(n,mu,sigma)
x<-as.matrix(cbind(x1=x[,1],x2=x[,2],x3=x[,3],x4=x[,4]))
p<-dim(x)[2]
b1<-c(1.5,-2.1,0.9,-0.4)
b2<-c(2,1.3,-2,1.5)
b3<-c(1.8,-3,2.1,1.5)
e1<-rnorm(n); e2<-rnorm(n); e3<-rnorm(n)
y<-as.matrix(cbind(x%*%b1+e1,x%*%b2+e2,x%*%b3+e3))
S<-crossprod(x,y)      
svd<-svd(S)
w1<-as.matrix(svd$u[,1])
u1<-as.matrix(svd$v[,1])
t1<-x%*%w1 
p1<-lm(x~t1+0)$coefficients    
q1<-lm(y~t1+0)$coefficients
x1<-x-t1%*%p1
y1<-y-t1%*%q1
S1<-crossprod(x1,y1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a function seems to be the obvious answer.  Here's one way to do it:

```
library(MASS)
p<-4
set.seed(88)
mu<-rep(0,p)
sigma<-diag(p)
n<-1000
x<-mvrnorm(n,mu,sigma)
x<-as.matrix(cbind(x1=x[,1],x2=x[,2],x3=x[,3],x4=x[,4]))
p<-dim(x)[2]
b1<-c(1.5,-2.1,0.9,-0.4)
b2<-c(2,1.3,-2,1.5)
b3<-c(1.8,-3,2.1,1.5)
e1<-rnorm(n); e2<-rnorm(n); e3<-rnorm(n)
y<-as.matrix(cbind(x%*%b1+e1,x%*%b2+e2,x%*%b3+e3))

params <- list(x=x, y=y)

doUpdate <- function(d) {
  S<-crossprod(x,y)      
  svd<-svd(S)
  w1<-as.matrix(svd$u[,1])
  u1<-as.matrix(svd$v[,1])
  t1<-x%*%w1 
  p1<-lm(x~t1+0)$coefficients    
  q1<-lm(y~t1+0)$coefficients
  x1<-x-t1%*%p1
  y1<-y-t1%*%q1
  S1<-crossprod(x1,y1)
  return(list(x=x1, y=y1))
}

for (i in 1:10) {
  params <- doUpdate(params)
}
```

obviously, you could use `lapply` or modify the number of times the loop is executed or use a `while`...

**EDIT**

In response to OP's request:

The `update` function becomes

```
# Note the corrections from my first version.  Apologies.
doUpdate <- function(d) {
  S<-crossprod(d$x, d$y)      
  svd<-svd(S)
  w1<-as.matrix(svd$u[,1])
  u1<-as.matrix(svd$v[,1])
  t1<-d$x%*%w1 
  p1<-lm(d$x~t1+0)$coefficients    
  q1<-lm(d$y~t1+0)$coefficients
  x1<-d$x-t1%*%p1
  y1<-d$y-t1%*%q1
  S1<-crossprod(x1,y1)
  # modify the elements of the return list to give you what you want
  return(list(x=x1, y=y1, w=w1, u=u1, p=p1, q=q1, t=t1, S=S1))
}
```

Usage is, for example:

```
#  Note the use of the global assignment 
results <- lapply(1:10, function(x) params <<- doUpdate(params))
```

To access the return values...

```
# S matrix after 1st iteration
results[[1]]$S
        [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
x1  475.6961  47.72836 -244.11710
x2 -170.5633 -34.31278   47.21138
x3 -313.3995 -52.32676  111.87913
x4 -807.4263 -92.04150  388.49945

# u vector after 7th iteration
results[[7]]$u
           [,1]
[1,]  0.6314637
[2,] -0.7181122
[3,]  0.2925209
# Evolution of the q vector
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
t1 -0.5126128 -3.111603 -1.39068
        [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
t1 -1.072562 -0.1267824 0.5054829
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
t1 0.02307118 0.02688335 0.04575242
           [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
t1 2.722651e+12 1.625811e+12 2.658938e+12
            [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
t1 -6.770723e+12 -1.349731e+13 -6.297258e+12
           [,1]         [,2]          [,3]
t1 1.331396e+12 582633428986 -579321816213
           [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
t1 1.295899e+13 -1.47372e+13 6.003158e+12
           [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
t1 2.395113e+26 1.535344e+27 1.217658e+27
           [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
t1 1.620474e+26 -1.20782e+27 4.573496e+26
            [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
t1 -3.638168e+27 7.517369e+27 5.804138e+27
```

Comment: These are the updated values of X, and y. I am interested to use the updated values again in place of X and y, and them perform the function again. Similiarly, for the 3rd time I will be having updated data matrix X, say X2 and response y2. The use this updated matrices in place of original X and y, and perform the calculation and so on. Finally, I have to store the values of w's, u's p's, q's and t's obtained after each iteration.

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question!  But in that case, replacing the `for` loop wirh an `lapply` and adding the variables you wish to save to the list returned by the function will give you a list-of-lists containing the information you need.

Comment: Sir, would you please help me developing th code.